# Is there a easy way to know what item was selected in LBN_SELCHANGE event?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know I can implement a variable to remember what was selected.
The reason why I want this feature is:
In LBN_SELCHANGE, I have user enter the password. If the password is wrong I won't allow the change, so I want the selected item to go back to where it was.
Thanks

Comment: I removed the Visual C++ part of the title and tag. It does not matter if you use Visual Stuido or some other IDE capable of using the windows api.

Comment: You should add some minimal code to your question. [mcve]

Comment: This is asking about a proposed solution rather than the problem you are trying to solve. The problem statement should be something like: *"How do I cancel a user-initiated selection change?"*

Comment: get it by send `LB_GETCURSEL`

Comment: `LBN_SELCHANGE` is sent to notify you that the selection *has* changed, not that it's *about to* change. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lbn-selchange) (**emphasis mine**): *Notifies the application that the selection in a list box **has changed** as a result of user input.* Note that *changed* is past-tense. If you want the previous value, you're going to have to store it somewhere yourself.

Comment: FWIW, your UI design is going to irritate your users. You should be checking privileges before the listbox is even shown, and the only items in it should be those the user is allowed to select. Putting them in front of the user when they don't have access is going to frustrate them, because there's no way in a listbox to disable the item to show that it's not accessible. Simply don't add them if the user has no access to select them instead.

Comment: Ken, I did implement a variable to remember the previous value. the application is working. thanks!

Comment: Ken, I agree with you if this is a normal desktop application. This program is an touch screen app used in a steel plant, the UI needs to be as "flat" as possible. Thanks.